# Django: no such table: users_profile

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, django-database

Django noob here. Whenever I extend the base User Model, and try to access or edit the new fields, I receive the following error [... table not found].

```
OperationalError at /admin/users/profile/
no such table: users_profile
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users/profile/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: users_profile
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py, line 413, in execute
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['/Users/rexmarkman/Desktop/ComputerScienceIA/newproject',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/rexmarkman/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 30 May 2021 12:52:22 +0000
```

Im not sure why this is happening as I have ran makemigrations and migrate multiple times. For reference here are my migrations

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Profile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('profile_picture', models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pictures')),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Also here is my models.py for further reference

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pictures') 

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Also worth noting that this issue occurs when attempting to change the profile table in the admin site

Please let me know if you need to know anything else.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Have you registered your model in `admin.py` ?

Comment: Yes I have! My code is split into the user application and the 'dashboard' application which contains most of the formatting. I've got the model registered in the user application's admin.py, do I need to also register it in the dashboard application's corresponding admin.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the `migrations` folder from your app and `db.sqilte3` file and then retry -:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

and then retry your error must be solved

Comment: Did this and upgraded Django to latest version, works perfectly now, thanks!